# Simulate gravitational pull on a body in orbit

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, easing, easing-functions

I'm trying to simulate gravitational pull/acceleration in the following animation. `earth`'s angular velocity should increase as it gets closer to `sol` and decrease as it gets far. I think I'll need an easing function to modify the `earth.angularVelocity` but no idea how.

I don't know if [already defined easing functions](http://easings.net/) or [a custom one](http://www.timotheegroleau.com/Flash/experiments/easing_function_generator.htm) would work. The easing function I need should work like in this graph:

[image: pull/relase easing function graph]

`earth`'s perihelion is at 180°, and aphelion is at 0/360°. How can I create such a function and make this work?

```
function pullRelease(angularPosition, begin, change, maxVelocity) {
    // ?
}
earth.angularVelocity = pullRelease(earth.angularPosition, 0, 360, 3);
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var sol = {
  x: 125,
  y: 150,
  r: 30,
  fill: "gold",
};

var orbit = {
  x: 200,
  y: 150,
  semiMajor: 150,
  semiMinor: 75,
};

var earth = {
  r: 15,
  fill: "dodgerblue",
  angularPosition: 0,
  angularVelocity: 1,
};

// draw sun
context.beginPath();
context.arc(sol.x, sol.y, sol.r, 0, 360 * Math.PI / 180);
context.fillStyle = sol.fill;
context.fill();
// draw fake sun to mark the orbit center
context.beginPath();
context.arc(orbit.x, orbit.y, sol.r, 0, 360 * Math.PI / 180);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,215,0,.1)";
context.fill();
// draw earth's orbit path
context.beginPath();
context.ellipse(orbit.x, orbit.y, orbit.semiMajor, orbit.semiMinor, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
// these are fixed, so save them as background-image
canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + canvas.toDataURL() + ")";

function draw() {
  context.resetTransform();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var newPosition = rotate(-earth.angularPosition, orbit.semiMajor, orbit.semiMinor, orbit.x, orbit.y);

  earth.x = newPosition.x;
  earth.y = newPosition.y;
  // earth.angularVelocity = pullRelease(earth.angularPosition, 0, 360, 3);
  earth.angularPosition += earth.angularVelocity;

  if (earth.angularPosition >= 360) {
    earth.angularPosition = 0;
  }
  position.innerHTML = earth.angularPosition + "°";

  context.translate(earth.x, earth.y);

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(0, 0, earth.r, 0, 360 * Math.PI / 180);
  context.closePath();
  context.fillStyle = earth.fill;
  context.fill();

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function rotate(angle, distanceX, distanceY, originX, originY) {
  return {
    x: originX + Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distanceX,
    y: originY + Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distanceY,
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: gainsboro;
}
canvas {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
#position {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="box" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<p>Position: <span id="position">0</span></p>
```

Comment: Gravity is just acceleration. See this answer to see how to simulate constant gravity:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194362/jumping-code-in-javascript/38194745#38194745 . For celestial objects you then just need to alter gravitational force by distance as per inverse square law (google it).

Comment: @slebetman In my case, there's no free space/dynamic objects. The only thing that's dynamic is `earth` (position) which follows a fixed path. I want its velocity to be dynamic too. I don't think I need complex physics calculations, but some sort of easing function. I've already got one working. It just needs some improvements.

Answer (score 2):

After some thinking, I've came up with a function which seems to work, but still I don't think the effect feels natural. Function produces the graph at left. An ideal one would be the one at right. So the function still needs some work.

[image]

```
function pullRelease(angularPosition, begin, change, minVelocity, maxVelocity) {
    var midWay = Math.floor(change/2);
    if (angularPosition >= begin && angularPosition < midWay) {
        var percent = angularPosition / midWay;
        return minVelocity + (maxVelocity-minVelocity) * percent;
    }
    else if (angularPosition == midWay) {
        return maxVelocity;
    }
    else if (angularPosition > midWay && angularPosition <= change) {
        var midWayOffset = angularPosition - midWay;
        var remaining    = midWay - midWayOffset;
        var percent      = remaining / midWay;
        return minVelocity + (maxVelocity-minVelocity) * percent;
    }
}
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var sol = {
  x: 125,
  y: 150,
  r: 30,
  fill: "gold",
};

var orbit = {
  x: 200,
  y: 150,
  semiMajor: 150,
  semiMinor: 75,
};

var earth = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  r: 15,
  fill: "dodgerblue",
  angularPosition: 0,
  angularVelocity: 0,
};

// draw sun
context.beginPath();
context.arc(sol.x, sol.y, sol.r, 0, 360 * Math.PI / 180);
context.fillStyle = sol.fill;
context.fill();
// draw fake sun to mark the orbit center
context.beginPath();
context.arc(orbit.x, orbit.y, sol.r, 0, 360 * Math.PI / 180);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,215,0,.1)";
context.fill();
// draw earth's orbit path
context.beginPath();
context.ellipse(orbit.x, orbit.y, orbit.semiMajor, orbit.semiMinor, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
// these are fixed, so save them as background-image
canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + canvas.toDataURL() + ")";

function draw() {
  context.resetTransform();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var newPosition = rotate(-earth.angularPosition, orbit.semiMajor, orbit.semiMinor, orbit.x, orbit.y);
  earth.x = newPosition.x;
  earth.y = newPosition.y;

  earth.angularVelocity = pullRelease(earth.angularPosition, 0, 360, 0.5, 5);
  earth.angularPosition += earth.angularVelocity;

  if (earth.angularPosition >= 360) {
    earth.angularPosition = 0;
  }
  position.innerHTML = Math.floor(earth.angularPosition) + "°";
  velocity.innerHTML = (earth.angularVelocity).toFixed(2) + "°";

  context.translate(earth.x, earth.y);

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(0, 0, earth.r, 0, 360 * Math.PI / 180);
  context.closePath();
  context.fillStyle = earth.fill;
  context.fill();

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function rotate(angle, distanceX, distanceY, originX, originY) {
  return {
    x: originX + Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distanceX,
    y: originY + Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distanceY,
  }
}

function pullRelease(angularPosition, begin, change, minVelocity, maxVelocity) {
  var midWay = Math.floor(change / 2);
  if (angularPosition >= begin && angularPosition < midWay) {
    var percent = angularPosition / midWay;
    return minVelocity + (maxVelocity - minVelocity) * percent;
  } else if (angularPosition == midWay) {
    return maxVelocity;
  } else if (angularPosition > midWay && angularPosition <= change) {
    var midWayOffset = angularPosition - midWay;
    var remaining = midWay - midWayOffset;
    var percent = remaining / midWay;
    return minVelocity + (maxVelocity - minVelocity) * percent;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: gainsboro;
}
canvas {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
#position {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  text-align: right;
}
#velocity {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="box" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<p>Position: <span id="position">0</span></p>
<p>Velocity: <span id="velocity">0</span></p>
```